# Rotating a camera using X, Y, Z

Tags: c++, math, rotation

First of all let me say I'm not that great with math, that is why I have came here to ask my question.

I have create a program where the camera is looking directly at the object I have, but I now want to rotate the camera around the object.

When the program is ran it creates an image, I am going to create multiple versions of the program to then create multiple images files which I can then put together to make it look like the camera is rotating around the object.

The two lines of code that I have for the my camera position and the direction it is looking at are as follows;

```
Vect campos(3, 1.5, -4);

Vect look_at(0,0,0);
```

I'm not asking for how to write code to make this rotation possible, all I am asking is how would I go about working out the different X,Y,Z for each of these values so that I can create a rotation around the object.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Your best bet is to draw it out on paper, or find a pre-existing piece of code on the internet. For figuring it out yourself, typical rotational movement follows `cos` and `sin` parametrisations. Then you put the camera position on a rotating orbit; finally, it needs to also be kept pointing towards the centre of rotation.

Comment: @MicroVirus Hi, thanks for your answer, I'm really not great with math so do you think you could explain to me on how to calculate it? Like all I'm looking for is to maybe get the points for every 20 degree rotation or something close to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a parametrisation for the circle, you can use:

```
x = r cos( t )
y = r sin( t )
z = z
```

This will rotate around the z-axis with radius `r` from the centre `(0,0,0)`. You could have your camera at such a point for any `t in [0, 2 pi]`.

Then, assuming your object of interest is at the centre of the coordinates ( `(0,0,0)` ) then your look-at is already set correctly.

Edit:
In C++ code, you could use the following:

```
// Add the math header to the top of the file with the includes
#include <math.h>
```

And then to get the camera positions:

```
double r = 3.0;
double t = 0.0;
double x = r * cos(t);
double y = r * sin(t);
double z = -4.0;

Vect campos(x, y, z);
Vect look_at(0,0,0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, see the problem I have is that I can't do the working out in code because the values need to be set as once the program is run, it renders the image. I need to be able to manually work out the coordinates and then type them in myself, if that makes sense?

Comment: @RonnieB555: You don't. Just change the angle `t` each time the program runs, and have the program use the formula's I supplied for calculating the effective rotation. Edit: And if it isn't your program to edit, use a calculator and the above formulae to manually calculate and then input the coordinates.

Comment: so in the calculator I would do the radius of the circle (how do I find this out by the way?) multiplied by the cos of the current x value I have?

Comment: @RonnieB555: You decide how far you want the camera to be from the object (=radius `r`) and the angle at which you want to look at it (=`t`), then from this follow the needed `X, Y, Z` coordinates.

Comment: so my code would be something like this?

x = 2 cos( 20 )
y = 2 sin( 20 )
z = -4

Vect campos(x, y, z);

Vect look_at(0,0,0);

The values 2 and 20 are just place holders.

Comment: @RonnieB555: Yes, if you translate that to valid c++ code then you have your answer.

Comment: Ok I have it like this, 
        int camx = 3 cos(20);
 int camy = 1.5 cos(20);
 int camz = -4;

 Vect campos(camx, camy, camz);

 Vect look_at(0,0,0);

But I'm getting these error on both the lines with cos, "Error 10 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cos'" and "Error 11 error C2668: 'cos' : ambiguous call to overloaded function"  Any suggestions?

Comment: @RonnieB555: I edited my answer to include C++ code. Remember to copy the parts to the correct location

Comment: wow thanks for writing it in C++, I have implemented it into my program and left all the values as you have put them, I then changed the value of t to equal 5 just to test to see if it was working and here are the results. The first image is with the values as you had then and the second is with t = 5.0 http://i268.photobucket.com/albums/jj28/ronnieb555/scene1_zps6d560f6e.png
http://i268.photobucket.com/albums/jj28/ronnieb555/scene_zps23964037.png

Comment: As you can see it is zooming in rather than rotating around, any suggestions?

Comment: I've tried increasing the radius as I thought maybe it was because I had it set too close, but changing the t value is still zooming it in and now. Do you mind if I post my code here and you could take a look?

Comment: Here is my main.cpp http://pastebin.com/hjKj1WUC

and here is my camera.h http://pastebin.com/akjuYhHh

The lines you gave me start at 319 on the main.cpp

Comment: @RonnieB555: From the code it seems that the plane/floor is in the X-Z plane, so you need to swap the code for Y and Z and probably tweak the constant value of -4.0 to be at the right side of the floor and the right height above the floor.

Comment: I swapped them around so that the Z was now using code that you provided and I also had cos on both instead of one as sin which was my mistake and it is working, thanks so much!!